# How to select specific elements in D3.js and change its color

Tags: javascript, d3.js, data-visualization

I have an assignment for my university course. It requires me to use an if-statement to select specific elements *("p" the paragraphs)* and change its color. I can't seem to do it. This is the code I have so far.

```
<body>
    <h1>Data Visualisation Journey Begins Here</h1>
    <script>
      var dataset = [14,5,26,23,9];

      d3.select("body").selectAll("p").data(dataset).enter().append("p").text(function(d,i){
          return "i = " + i + " d = " +d;
      }).style("fill", function(d){ 
        if(d[i] % 2 !== 0 )
         { return "red"}
      });
    </script>
  </body>
```

This is how the program should look like later:

[image]

Comment: What elements? You didn't explain the specific rule.

Comment: The "p" element. Sorry. The paragraphs which correspond to the odd elements in the dataset should be red.

Comment: (I know it's the p, I was asking *"which paragraphs"*) It's just `if(d % 2 !== 0 )`. The datum `d` itself is a number, not an array, so drop the index.

Comment: Thx @GerardoFurtado managed to fix it. I also should use color instead of fill.